# php class member array being inappropriately cached

Tags: php

Let's say I have the following:

```
<?php
class MyClass {
  public $validThings = array("Stuff");

  //checks to see if $input is in the array $validThings
  public function valid($input) {
    return is_int(array_search($input, $this->validThings);
  }
}
```

We would expect the following:

```
$myClassInstance->valid("Stuff");//finds 'Stuff'
$myClassInstance->valid("Things");//doesn't find 'Things'
```

Now lets say that I change the code for the initialization of $validThings to:

```
public $validThings = array("Stuff", "Things");
```

We would expect:

```
$myClassInstance->valid("Stuff");//finds 'Stuff'
$myClassInstance->valid("Things");//finds 'Things'
```

The behavior I'm seeing, though, is that the second call still won't find 'Things'. I suspect this has something to do with how PHP is cached, but I don't know what specifically. It is highly reproducible: I can change the array any which way in code, and so long as I don't modify that member variable within a function call it will hold onto the original value... *even across apache hard restarts*.

Has anyone seen this who can explain the behavior?

To clarify a point: there is some form of caching behavior going on here that has to do with some implementation detail of php or caching around php. This is not a code bug; it is merely a behavior revealed by this code. Also, we're using [hidef](http://pecl.php.net/package/hidef), which may be a salient detail and php 5.2.10

Comment: Your comment on the second example says "doesn't find `Things`"...you mean "does find things"?

Comment: Your function never `return`s anything...

Comment: The exact semantics of valid() aren't important. I could be returning something or simply outputting the value of $validThings. The issue isn't there.

Comment: The implementation of valid() are important. That's where the bug is.

Comment: @AndrewR I disagree that this is a code bug and not an expected behavior of some sort that I don't understand. var_dump and physical inspection of the member variable reveal the same thing; across apache restarts the code being used by the php interpreter is not fully updated unless I explicitly modify that variable.

Comment: PHP isn't "cached". I ran this with `return in_array($input, $this->validThings);` and I am getting expected results.

Comment: Also, with your is_int implementation, it is working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Your method is not returning anything it should have been

```
 return array_search($input, $this->validThings);
```

`array_search` can sometimes return `0` if the element is the first which can be interpreted in PHP as `false` sometimes so you should use this example instead ;

```
class MyClass {
    public $validThings = array("Stuff");
    public function valid($input) {
        return array_search($input, $this->validThings) !== false;
    }
}

$myClassInstance = new MyClass();
var_dump($myClassInstance->valid("Stuff")); //true
var_dump($myClassInstance->valid("Things")); //false
```

**Edit**

Or Better sill you can just use

```
    public function valid($input) {
        return in_array($input, $this->validThings);
    }
```

Comment: I've modified the question for clarity. The array_search function is not at issue; I'm seeing the same behavior with and without using that function. For instance, if I var_dump the value of $validThings it only has 'Stuff', even if the code clearly contains 'Things'.

Comment: What is your exact `var_dump` out .. and what code are you testing with , which is also your PHP version ??

Comment: The ternary is not necessary. You just need `return array_search($input, $this->validThings) !== false;`

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the problem was that `$validThings` was being serialized and loaded back into the object. This should have been diagnosable from the fact that it was persistent across apache restarts; not a caching issue so much as being persisted.

PHP does not re-initialize a class instance on de-serialization, so the member variable is whatever was saved the first time it was created, even though the class changed.